# Multiple Find and replace in Notepad++ using regular expression

Tags: notepad++

is there any way to make Multiple Find and Replace in Notepad++ in the same time.

I am using regular expression to find and replace.

I have large number of files and I need to find and replace 10 items for each files.

Comment: No. You have to do them one after another.

Comment: May it can be done by Notepad++ macro?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fairly new to Notepad++ but I've had success in doing this using a macro:

- Open your file
- Hit Macro > Start recording
- ctrl + F: find and replace first item, find + replace second, third, N-items
- Hit Macro > Stop recording
- Hit Macro > Save recording and give it a good name and possibly shortcut

To run the macro:

- Open your file
- Hit Macro > and select your saved macro / or use the shortcut you choose

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Click record macro button
2. Press Ctrl+F
3. Search the term you're looking to find
4. After finding the term, press **Escape** on your keyboard
5. Do the actions you desire to do around the found term.
6. Stop recording Macro
7. Run the macro you just recorded as many times as needed.

I was looking to get a list of text surrounded by a specific HTML tag. This is what worked for me, hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I depends on exactly what you want to find and replace.

Search and replace is rather limited in Notepad++, and there is currently no way to perform multiple search and replace operations at the same time.

*But your can get creative if your needs fall within the current limitations of Notepad++.*

If you want to find multiple different strings and replace them with the same (or similar) strings, you can use regular expressions.  In the simplest form, you can add a pipe symbol in a regex, and it will act as an "or" operator.

For example, you can specify regular expression search and search for: `foo|bar`

For your replacement string, use whatever you like.  For example: `baz`

Now when you perform your search, it will replace all `foo`s and `bar`s with `baz`.

You can even get a littler fancier and search for something like: `(f)oo|ba(r)`

This time, for your replacement string, use `$1$2az`.

Now all `foo`s will be replaced with `faz` and all `bar`s will be replaced with `raz`.

Comment: Downvoter, any reason for the downvote and what would improve this answer?  Or is this just the usual troll? We both know who you are.